# Chrome is throwing a credentials window or a proxy pop up before we hit the url through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, sikuli

As soon as we hit chrome, sometimes, a proxy credentials window/pop-up appears before we hit the URL through Selenium Java. This is stopping script run.

FYI, username:password@url is not working since that is coming before we hit the URL.

We don't know the solution approach for this issue.

Information:

1. We are using an Azure cloud server for Automation and script development activity. Here we are using a Client proxy to access client application for automation purpose.
2. We are using Eclipse IDE, Java, Selenium for script development and automation where we extract code JARs and deploy in bots to run.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried by putting alert check? If Alert is present then enter the credentials else continue with execution.

Comment: I checked it doesn't come under alert. Did not work that part.

Comment: It's seems like SSO issue. You may need to talk to admin or developer.

Comment: But my question is SSO shall be for a URL know. In this case, it is like Selenium WebDriver is launching chrome and it shows up before URL hit. So, I wonder who is the point of contact here.

Comment: I noticed that there is a sikuli tag...
If you use sikuli you can wait(or just verify) that let say "Sign in" button exist, then type credentials and type enter